# The type javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, jersey

I am developing a Rest Client test program. I am new to this. From net I downloaded jersey-client-1.19.4.jar and added to Build Path in the eclipse. Every thing is fine except that webResource.accept gives below error.

> The type javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType cannot be resolved

I am referring to REST Tutorials mentioned in below URL as reference for my test program development.

[REST Client Tutorial](http://www.javainterviewpoint.com/restful-java-client-jersey-client/)

Below is my code: Kindly help

```
import java.io.*;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("File Name: "+args[0]);
    String fileName = args[0];

    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/iso2code/AX");
    ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);

    if (response.getStatus() != 200) 
    {
       throw new Exception("Exception Occured - HTTP Error Code : "
        + response.getStatus());
    }

    String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

    System.out.println("Fetching Output....");
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

}

Comment: First,Jax-Rs 2.x (Jersey 2x) is better than 1.x, how can you have  'javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType cannot be resolved' exception from Jax-RS 1.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded Jersey Client 1.19.4 from the [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-client/1.19.4)

and I got the same problem as you.

This is how I overcome the problem:

If your project is not maven, convert it to maven.
Then go to pom.xml and add this:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.4</version>
</dependency>
```

to your `<dependencies>` tag.

Answer (score 4):

The solution from @yoav is great, but if someone has the same issue and doesn't want / need to convert to maven (which is better for dependency management) you just need to include all files from the zip file that you find following this [link](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.sun.jersey/jersey-client/1.19.4/source-code).

You will find:

- jersey-client-1.19.4.jar
- jersey-core-1.19.4.jar
- jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar

Put all of them into your lib.